# Optimized way to find in which range does a number lie

Tags: python

I have multiple ranges lets say 1-1000, 1000-2000, 2000-3000, 3000-4000, 4000-5000. I get a number from the user and now i need to find in which range it lies. One way to do this would be to create multiple if statement and check from there like so:

```
if num>=1 and num < 1000:
    print "1"
elif num >=1000 and num < 2000:
    print "2"
....
```

This method would create a lot of branches.

Is there an optimized way to do this without so many branches and in the least complexity?

PS: I just wrote the code in python since its shorter to write but this can be case in any language. Also the range and output can be very different. 
The range and output are examples and can be anything like 1-100, 100-1000, 1000-1500 etc and output like "Very Low, low, medium" something like that.

Comment: Divide by 1000 and round up?

Comment: This is the case for this particular example. What if the output i have to provide is not number but something else entirely? Also what if the ranges are not equally spaced?

Comment: How would you range it if it is not a number or something numberish?

Comment: @PrateekGupta if there is no pattern in the ranges, you will need to evaluate all possibilities. At best, you might want to optimize how you start searching.

Answer (score 1):

Store the starting or ending of the range in the list and sort it along with number to find its exact range.

```
import numpy as np
start = [1,1000,2000,3000,4000]
print(list(np.sort(start+[num])).index(num))
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe just divide by 1000 and take the entire part :

here example in python :

```
>>> x=3608
>>> int(x/1000+1)
4
```

Following your comment/edit in your post, if you need a different output (a string for example) you can (in python) use a `dict` :

```
>>> Output={'1': 'very low', '2': 'low', '3': 'medium','4':'high' }
>>> x=2954
>>> Output[str(int(x/1000+1))]
'medium'
```

Comment: It should print `4` for `3608` not `2` check the OP's question

Answer (score 0):

```
my_range=(1,1000), (1000,2000), (2000,3000), (3000,4000), (4000,5000)
my_output='Very Low, Low, Medium, High, Very High'.split(', ')
num=3565
for k,i in enumerate(my_range):
   if i[0]<=num<i[1]:print(my_output[k]);break
else:
   print('Out of range')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your ranges don't follow any particular logic, there's not much you can do except testing them one by one, but you can still simplify the code by using a loop:

```
ranges = [[0,1000],[1500,1600],[1200,1220]]

def find_range(num, ranges)
    for low, high in ranges:
        if low <= num < high:
            return low, high # or any other formating using a dict for example
```

Of course you can optimize a bit by sorting your ranges and then doing a binary search instead of linear...

Comment: binary search is a nice touch which will help quite a bit. Just for clarification though the number of branches is not reduced in this right,  instead complexity is increased to make the code simple?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "branches" if it's number of `if` tests then this is exactly the same as your code, no better no worse (just better written): linear with number of ranges `n`. If you do implement binary search then it will be massively reduced to `log(n)`, with potentially a one-off `n log(n)` overhead for sorting your ranges if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Suspect that you have *many* breaks and require an optimized search, you can go with bisection on an ordered list of breakpoints resulting in a logarithmic time consumption:

```
import random
import time


def split_pivot(intervals, number):
    """Divide and conquer recursively."""
    if len(intervals) == 1:
        return intervals[0]
    if len(intervals) == 2:
        if number >= intervals[1][1][0]:
            return intervals[1]
        elif number < intervals[0][1][1]:
            return intervals[0]
        else:
            raise

    pivot = int(len(intervals) // 2.0)

    if number < intervals[pivot][1][1]:
        return split_pivot(intervals[:pivot + 1], number)
    elif number >= intervals[pivot + 1][1][0]:
        return split_pivot(intervals[pivot + 1:], number)
    else:
        raise


if __name__ == '__main__':
    UPPER_BOUND = 10000000

    newbreak = 0
    manybreaks = []
    while newbreak < UPPER_BOUND:
        step = int(random.random() * 10) + 1
        manybreaks.append(newbreak + step)
        newbreak = manybreaks[-1]
    print('Breaks: {:d}'.format(len(manybreaks)))

    intervals = [
        (idx, (manybreaks[idx], manybreaks[idx + 1]))
        for idx in range(len(manybreaks) - 1)
    ]
    print('Intervals: {:d}'.format(len(intervals)))
    print(
        '  Example: idx {tpl[0]:d}, lower {tpl[1][0]:d}, upper {tpl[1][1]:d}'
        .format(tpl=random.choice(intervals)))

    thenumber = int(random.random() * UPPER_BOUND)
    print('Number: {:d}'.format(thenumber))

    t0 = time.time()
    result = split_pivot(intervals, thenumber)
    t1 = time.time()

    print('Result: {e[0]:d} ({e[1][0]:d}, {e[1][1]:d})'.format(e=result))
    print('  Done in {:.4f}s'.format(t1 - t0))
```

The result of the search itself is (on my machine) below 0.05 seconds. The generation of breakpoints and corresponding intervals runs for roughly 4.5 seconds:

```
Breaks: 1818199
Intervals: 1818198
  Example: idx 605849, lower 3330441, upper 3330446
Number: 6951844
Result: 1263944 (6951843, 6951847)
  Done in 0.0436s
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
ranges = {
    0: 'undefined range',
    1000: '1',
    1500: '2',
    2500: '3'
}

num = 500

print(ranges[max(ranges, key=lambda x: num < x)])
```

Output: 1